# Compiled Python script "No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, handler

My problem is very similar to this question already asked:
[No handlers could be found for logger paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152578/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-paramiko)

The difference is that my script will run perfectly fine in the Python interpreter but will throw the mentioned error when compiled with PyInstaller to an exe file.  I have tried a couple different logging handlers with no luck, and  I'm shooting for a self-containted executable I can run from any Windows system.  Here is my script for reference:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='hp_procurve', ip='10.1.2.20', username='myusername', password='mypassword')  
output = net_connect.send_command("show run")
print output
net_connect.disconnect()
raw_input("Press enter to exit...")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try the solution from that link, using `paramiko.util.log_to_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a console handler (for example) to paramiko.transport:

```
paramiko_logger = logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport')
if not paramiko_logger.handlers:
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s| PARAMIKO: '
                          '%(lineno)03d@%(module)-10s| %(message)s')
        )
    paramiko_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks fernandezcuesta. That fixed my error!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs across this, here is my full Python script to SSH into an HP ProCurve switch and print the output of a "show run" command.  I ran into another error where the cryptography module would not interact properly with PyInstaller after the mentioned error in this post was solved.  This link provides that solution:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2013

```
def patch_crypto_be_discovery():
    from cryptography.hazmat import backends
    try:
        from cryptography.hazmat.backends.commoncrypto.backend import backend as be_cc
    except ImportError:
        be_cc = None
    try:
        from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend as be_ossl
    except ImportError:
        be_ossl = None
    backends._available_backends_list = [
        be for be in (be_cc, be_ossl) if be is not None
]
import logging
paramiko_logger = logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport')
if not paramiko_logger.handlers:
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s| PARAMIKO: '
                      '%(lineno)03d@%(module)-10s| %(message)s')
    )
paramiko_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='hp_procurve', ip='10.1.2.20', username='myusername', password='mypassword')  
output = net_connect.send_command("show run")
print output
net_connect.disconnect()
raw_input("Press enter to exit...")
```

I also needed to run this command to compile the script to an exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl --hidden-import cffi HP-ProCurve-ShowRun.py
```