# Paramiko Python: No handlers for paramiko.transport - Getting TypeError

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Alright, so i am trying to implement paramiko in my python script.
The aim is to connect to another PC in the same LAN and execute the command through python.

My python version:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
```

I have a basic code here:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

host = '192.168.xx.xx'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

But then I get the following error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testbed.py", line 8, in <module>
    client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 385, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 543, in start_client
    raise e
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152578/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-paramiko

Comment: @FranciscoRodríguez The answer in the link didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error didn't said much

So first I handled `No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"` with adding at the top of my script

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
paramiko.util.log_to_file("/tmp/example.log")   <= to redirect the logs to a file
```

Then I `cat /tmp/example.log` and found this error
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4010 (it happens to do with cryptography lib.)

Looking around, I found that there are two libs ( `enum` and `enum34` ) and above

```
>>> import cryptography
>>> cryptography.__version__
'2.1.3'
```

you need `enum34` vs the default that pip is installing ( `enum` )

Personally I had another problem, that I first installed `enum34` globally vs personal with `--user` so I did

```
pip uninstall enum
pip uninstall enum --user
pip install enum34 --user
```

That worked for me, hope it helps